# Eclipse project dependencies

Tags: eclipse, build, path

My Eclipse project has no source and a lot of referenced librairies built automaticaly with a script. I want to create multiple subproject which include all these referenced libairies. When I add the parent project as a dependency for my subproject, referenced librairies are not imported. How can I fix it ? (I use Mars Eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found answer myself : To Eclipse buildpath configuration screen : Go to order and export tab and ticks checkbox of librairies you want export.